# How to select unique date from datetime column in sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite3-python

[This is how DB looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojIM1.png)

I want to get only dates without any time
like: [('2023-07-28',), ('2023-07-29',), ...]

I've already tried:
CURSOR.execute(f"SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) FROM {name}_schedule WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) >= DATE('now') LIMIT(6) OFFSET({count})")

But i got dates with time: [('2023-07-28',), ('2023-07-28',), ('2023-07-28',), ('2023-07-29',), ('2023-07-29',), ('2023-07-29',)]

Comment: The output in the last paragraph doesn't contain times.

Comment: You SPECIFICALLY asked it for only the date (`strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date)`).  If you want the whole date, then just do `SELECT date`.  That will create Python datetime objects, and you can format those however you want.   Also, can't you just do `WHERE date >= now`?  Why do you insist on converting to strings?  SQL handles dates and times very competently.

Comment: These dates are identical, three times 28th of July three times 29th of July
I want [('2023-07-28',), ('2023-07-29',), ...]

Comment: So, are you saying you only want one record for each date?  Why didn't you say that?  `SELECT UNIQUEROW` will do that.

Comment: UNIQUEROW causes an error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error /

CURSOR.execute(f"SELECT UNIQUEROW strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) FROM {name}_schedule WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) >= DATE('now') LIMIT(6) OFFSET({count})")

Comment: If only want unique dates then try `SELECT DISTINCT(strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date)) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CURSOR.execute(f"SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) FROM {name}_schedule WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) >= DATE('now') LIMIT(6) OFFSET({count})")
```

DISINCT choosing only unique values, so the problem solved